# How should I understand the sentence structure in 你在这儿写了很多?

Tags: grammar, word-order, sentence

I went through similar questions but haven't seen something as simple as my question.

In the online course I am following this example is given:

> 你在这儿写了很多。

Though, AFAIK the sentence structure is S+t+p+how+Verb(+object) according to the "Chinese Grammar" app.
Thus, I would expect the correct sentence to be 你在这儿很多写了, since 很多 clearly is not an object (in fact, falls to the "how" category) and is not supposed to come to the end.

Can somebody clarify this, please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

我觉得“很多”是程度补语？在谓词后作为表程度的补语。

不是很懂语法一类的东西，但可以肯定“你在这儿很多写了”是错的。

如果你在一张纸上写了“很多”俩字，有人指着它对你说“你在这儿写了很多”，那么这句话应该写作“你在这儿写了‘很多’”，这个时候这个“很多”就是宾语了

I guess maybe "很多" is degree complement here? In Chinese, "Degree Complement is used after a verb or an adjective to explain the degree of an action, the nature of a thing or the reached degree of a state."

Not so familiar with grammar theory things, but I know “你在这儿很多写了” is wrong, I can understand “你在这儿写了很多”，“你写了很多在这儿”，“在这儿，你写了很多”，“很多字(note here)被你写在这儿” easier.

If you have wrote "很多" in a paper, then someone pointed the paper and said "You have wrote '很多' here", the "很多" in that sentence will be an object, otherwise this sentence should mean "You have wrote a lot"

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to what you suggested, I find it more natural to think of 很多 as an object in this context, that is, "many (words)." *很多寫了 is ungrammatical.

很 is an adverb meaning "much" and 多 is an adjective meaning "many," so the combination 很多 should be parsed as an adjective. We can use 很 as a leading adverb in 很愛他 "love him a lot" and 得很多 as a trailing adverbial phrase in 吃得很多 "eat a lot" (literally, "eat to the degree of a lot") but I cannot see how 很多 can be used as an adverb.

The adverb 在這兒 indeed goes in front of the verb. 你寫了很多在這兒 is also grammatical; the difference is emphasis is tiny.

Answer (score 3):

I think a complete sentence should be "你在这儿写了很多**廢話**", in which 廢話 is the object, and 很多(very much) is the adverb that modifies the verb 写了(wrote). Here, the adverb is followed by the phrase - 廢話.

The sentence you wrote is incorrect, as the adverb should be followed by an adjective, another adverb, or a noun phrase. It makes sense if you say: "你在这儿 **很多 都 写 錯了**" (adv + adj + verb + phrase/the object).

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing, it is not unreasonable to assume you are writing words. So if I leave that out, I think you will still get the gist.

I think this phenomenon is called ellipsis.

Chinese loves ellipsis! Of course native speakers know what is missing, but for a foreigner, this can be a big problem! Drives me crazy sometimes!

In a Chinese lesson:

你在这儿写了很多（字）。
You wrote a lot of characters here.
你知道这些词都是什么意思吗？
Do you know what all these words mean?

Answer (score 1):

你在这儿写了很多。this is the correct one.

"你在这儿写了很多",in English, would be ---- you wrote a lot here, so when you want to say this in Mandarin, you need to rearrange the order of words in this way-- you(你)+ here(在这)+ wrote(写了)+ a lot(很多).

examples:

1. I have had breakfast at home.
   我（I）+ 在家(at home)+ 吃过(have had)+ 早饭(breakfast)
2. I bought 1kg oranges in the supermarket.
   我（I)+在超市(in the supermarket)+买了(bought)+一公斤橘子(1 kg oranges)

Answer (score 1):

The already given answers may be over-complicating things, since in this case the english equivalent is almost the same:

> "You have written a lot here"

This is very usual in (also spoken) Chinese, and the same for other "adverbial" (?) constructs, like 我这次吃了很多 or 我们吃得很好

Since such common constructs can be seen everywhere in standard idiom, IMHO it is easier to not focus on the grammatical background too much but just use it as a pattern.